# Depth of a json tree

Tags: python, json, depth

I have a tree of the form:

```
{  
    "id":442500000904671234,
    "reply":0,
    "children":[  
        {  
            "id":442500532536893440,
            "reply":1,
            "children":[  
                {  
                    "id":442500826561785856,
                    "reply":1,
                    "children":[  
                        {  
                            "id":442501277688545280,
                            "reply":1,
                            "children":[  
                                {  
                                    "id":442501561940709376,
                                    "reply":1,
                                    "children":[  
                                        {  
                                            "id":442501884709199872,
                                            "reply":1,
                                            "children":[  

                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "id":442500099315597312,
            "reply":0,
            "children":[  

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I find maximum depth of the tree in python?

Comment: Try incrementing a counter when you go deeper with `{`, but decrementing when you close out with `}`. Each time, check if your counter is greater than your current max.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse JSON with python's [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library and then calculate depth with recursive function.

```
import json

def depth(jsn):
    if jsn.has_key('children'):
        return 1 +  max([0] + map(depth, jsn['children']))
    else:
        return 1

j = json.load(file('your_file.json'))
print depth(j)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked but can u suggest me some tutorial on other such functions like map. Actually I have to do some  detailed analysis on json tree.

Comment: [this one](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~erdmann/mse350/topics/list_comprehensions.html) is pretty readable

Comment: this is a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stack to push the { and then when you meet a } before you pop you check if your current depth is greater than the maximum depth that you got so far, that is if the stack.count is greater than the maximum count already achieved.

I'll update my answer after work with a code example

Comment: I also want to know the number of children at each level.

Answer (score 0):

What about loading json into `dict` and traversing tree. At least should give some ideas to go further.

```
import json

def depth(root):
    if root is None:
        return 0
    if isinstance(root, list):
        return max(map(depth, root)) + 1
    if not isinstance(root, dict):
        return 1
    return max(depth(v) for k, v in root.items()) + 1

print depth(json.load(file('your_data.json')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just walk the tree using DFS or BFS and count the depth as you go:

```
#load in your data
json_tree = json.loads(your_data)

depth = 0

if json_tree:
    depth += 1

#add a root node + it's depth
to_visit = [(json_tree, depth)] 

max_depth = 0

while to_visit:
    #get first from the list
    current = to_visit.pop(0)

    #if depth greater than the current max update max 
    if current[1] > max_depth:
        max_depth = current[1]

    # append all children to the list with increased depth
    for child in current[0]['children']:
        to_visit.append((child, current[1] + 1))


print(max_depth)
```

the benefit of doing it this way is that you actually go over your data structure rather than rely on the string representation

Answer (score 0):

convert json to dict,

```
count_global = 0


def find_depth(tree_dict=None, count=0):

    if not tree_dict['children']:
        global count_global
        if count_global < count:
            count_global = count

    for child in tree_dict['children']:
        count = count + 1
        find_depth(child, count)
```

Comment: IMO, locking should be done to count_global, which I did not do!