# Depth of binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

I have created a class with Node:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

And fill the tree with some data, I want depth of a tree without recursion:

```
def depth(self, data):
    self.depth = dict()
    root = self.dict[self.root] # this works, I got the root, it is declared in another init
    if root.data == data:
        return 0
    q = set()
    q.add(0)
    q.add(root)
    while q:
        element = q.pop()
        if type(element) == int: 
            if q == set():      
                break
            else:
                key = element
                q.add(element+1)
        else:
            v = element
            try:
                self.depth[v.data].add(key)
            except KeyError:
                self.depth[v.data] = key
            if v.right is not None:
                q.add(v.right)
            if v.left is not None:
                q.add(v.left)
            if data == v.data:
               break
    return self.depth[data]
```

This code should return the depth of element data. It works with lists, but I have timeout with them so I must use set instead. With sets it gets wrong results. (For example 19 instead of 6)

Comment: Why do you not want to use recursion to find the depth of the tree?

Comment: Code is tested by a huge ammount of Nodes, where is reached the maximum recursion.

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of `q`? You put different types of things in it, namely numbers and `Node`s.

Comment: If you're not going to use recursion, then just use a stack.

Comment: That 0 means depth in integer, If type of element is int than it goes +1 and if type is Node than, load left,right and save the depth into dict.

Comment: I think your problems stem from the fact that you rely on stuff being ordered... whereas sets are not, and you pop random elements leading to your key being possibly not populated at all.... which obviously doesn't do what you expect it to do... i would suggest re-writing the depth storage no to be in the set on it's own and be stored with each node processed, my previous answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005959/depth-of-a-json-tree/29006807#29006807

Comment: Yes, you' re right I forgot that set pop() is different, thanks.

Comment: So are you saying that you don't do anything to balance the tree and therefore the depth could be as high as 'n' where 'n' is the number of nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I translated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19914505/2896874) into Python:

```
def maxdepth(r):
    depth = 0
    wq = []
    path = []
    wq.append(r)
    while wq:
        r = wq[-1]
        if path and r == path[-1]:
            if len(path) > depth:
                depth = len(path)
            path.pop()
            wq.pop()
        else:
            path.append(r)
            if r.right is not None:
                wq.append(r.right)
            if r.left is not None:
                wq.append(r.left)
    return depth
```